# day pilot scheduler showing error in mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, daypilot

i am using day pilot in mvc , in view page i am getting error for this daypilot

Exception :

```
System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'DayPilotScheduler' and the best extension method overload 
'DayPilot.Web.Mvc.DayPilotExtensions.DayPilotScheduler(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, string, DayPilot.Web.Mvc.DayPilotSchedulerConfig has some invalid arguments
```

Actual Code :

```
@Html.DayPilotScheduler("dps", new DayPilotSchedulerConfig { BackendUrl = Url.Content("~/Scheduler/Backend"), EventResizeHandling = EventResizeHandlingType.CallBack, EventMoveHandling = EventMoveHandlingType.CallBack, TimeRangeSelectedHandling = TimeRangeSelectedHandlingType.CallBack, CellGroupBy = GroupBy.Month, CellDuration = 1440, Days = 365, StartDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, 1, 1) })
```

Comment: @Html.DayPilotScheduler("dps", new DayPilotSchedulerConfig
{
    BackendUrl = Url.Content("~/Scheduler/Backend"),
    EventResizeHandling = EventResizeHandlingType.CallBack,
    EventMoveHandling = EventMoveHandlingType.CallBack,
    TimeRangeSelectedHandling = TimeRangeSelectedHandlingType.CallBack,
    CellGroupBy = GroupBy.Month,
    CellDuration = 1440,
    Days = 365,
    StartDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, 1, 1)
})  In this @html.daypilot showing error

Comment: After looking at code, it seems that @Html.DayPilotScheduler() requires 3 arguments & you have passed only 2 (if I am not wrong).